# Do loop keeps on repeating

Tags: javascript

So my alternative version of this code is in Java, the logic is fairly similar although in JavaScript the userinput is repeated infinitely rather than carrying until the user loses. This is my working Java code for reference:

```
int stop =0;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random rand = new Random();

    do {
        int card;
        int upcommingcard;
        String userinput;

        card= rand.nextInt(13)+1;
        System.out.println("Card is "+card);
        System.out.println("Higher or Lower?");
        userinput = scan.next();
        upcommingcard = rand.nextInt(13)+1;

        if(!userinput.equalsIgnoreCase("H")&&(!userinput.equalsIgnoreCase("L"))){
            System.out.println("Invalid Input ");
        }
        else if((userinput.equalsIgnoreCase("H")) && (upcommingcard > card)){
            System.out.println("Correct!");
        }
        else if(userinput.equalsIgnoreCase("L") && upcommingcard < card){
            System.out.println("Correct!l ");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("You lost it was " + upcommingcard);
            stop=1;

        }
    }while (stop != 1);
}
```

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
JavaScript - Not working

```
var max=13;
var min=1;
var stop=0;
var card = Math.floor((Math.random() * (13 - 1) + 1));
var userinput = prompt("Card is "+card+"... Higher or lower?");
var upcommingcard = Math.floor((Math.random() * (13 - 1) + 1));
do{


    if((userinput !="H")&&(userinput !="L")){
        console.log("Invalid input");

    }
    else if((userinput ="H")&&(upcommingcard > card)){
        console.log("Correct!");

    }
    else if((userinput ="L")&&(upcommingcard < card)){
        console.log("Correct!");

    }
    else{
        console.log("You lost, it was "+ upcommingcard);
        stop=1;

}
}
while(stop !=1);
```

Just to mention also that it registers that the user's input is correct although it fails to continue and just keeps on spitting out the same output until the browser crashes.

EDIT: Thanks for the responses! the loop works perfectly now, my only issue is that the logic is a bit flawed since sometimes I Input 'L' for 8 and upcoming int is 10.. Dispite this I get the Incorrect response.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: You're only calling `prompt` once before the `do...while`. Put it a the top of the do while.

Comment: Essentially My java script version doesn't work and keeps on outputting the same answer rather than continue and eventually crashes. Where as in my java version it stops when the user loses.

Comment: I see you are using `=` instead of `==` for your "equal to" comparisons. At the moment you are reassigning the values instead of comparing them.

Comment: The Java version has the "logic"/"function" in the loop. Why did you partly move it out of the loop in the JavaScript part? And there's a huge difference between `=` and `==`/`===`

Comment: Ahh I ask for someone for help earlier today, they mention messing around with the operators due to the Strings correlating with the ints. My mistake! Thanks for the advice.

Comment: I need to mention that the upcoming card values will be the same every time in your Javascript :)

Comment: Try running the code I answered with and see if it does what you want.

Answer (score 0):

It's not that your console isn't updating, it's that you never exit your loop if the input is incorrect, and you never offer them the option to try again.

Thus if they are incorrect, the loop will never end, the console won't be updated, and they can't retry.

I would recommend changing the code to the following, to alert the user to try again.

```js
var max = 13;
var min = 1;
var stop = 0;
var card = Math.floor((Math.random() * (13 - 1) + 1));
var userinput = prompt("Card is " + card + "... Higher or lower?");
var upcommingcard = Math.floor((Math.random() * (13 - 1) + 1));
do {


  if ((userinput != "H") && (userinput != "L")) {
    console.log("Invalid input");
    alert("Invalid input!");
    userinput = prompt("Card is " + card + "... Higher or lower?");

  } else if ((userinput == "H") && (upcommingcard > card)) {
    console.log("Correct!");
    alert("Correct!");
    stop = 1;

  } else if ((userinput == "L") && (upcommingcard < card)) {
    console.log("Correct!");
    alert("Correct!");
    stop = 1;

  } else {
    console.log("You lost, it was " + upcommingcard);
    alert("You lost, it was " + upcommingcard);
    stop = 1;

  }
}
while (stop != 1);
```

Comment: Here I thought the game is supposed to go on until the user makes a wrong guess.

Comment: @ionizer That'd certainly be a way to improve it, and increment a score, but since OP didn't include a score I didn't want to alter their intention too much.

Comment: Ahh thanks for your response! not what I was quite looking for although was beneficial towards me fixing my issue ! I would upvote if I could although my rep stops me until I hit 15.

Comment: Regardless, it does not change the fact that the `if` comparison is invalid and will endlessly repeat if that `stop = 1` is removed from the guess checks.

Answer (score 0):

There are some points I want to make on this:

1. Your Java and Javascript code logic differs. You had the variables and input reads inside `do while` in Java but outside in Javascript.
2. As your `prompt` right now is outside the loop, it will keep having the same input value everytime and not asking for another one, and will carry on until it's a wrong guess, or forever if it's an invalid input. And the next point worsens your problem:
3. Your `if` comparison operators are invalid. What you did, as mentioned in the comments, is a data assignment to `userinput` and will always return correct

That being said, I corrected it below while adding alert popups instead of `console.log` only:

```js
var stop = 0;

do {
  var card = Math.floor((Math.random() * (13 - 1) + 1));
  var userinput = prompt("Card is " + card + "... Higher or lower?");
  var upcommingcard = Math.floor((Math.random() * (13 - 1) + 1));

  if ((userinput != "H") && (userinput != "L")) {
    console.log("Invalid input");
    alert("Invalid input");
    stop = 1; //Currently stopping if having invalid input, you can remove this later
  } else if ((userinput == "H") && (upcommingcard > card)) {
    //Note the '==' above, and also the next one for comparing equal values
    console.log("Correct!");
    alert("Correct");
  } else if ((userinput == "L") && (upcommingcard < card)) {
    console.log("Correct!");
    alert("Correct!");
  } else {
    console.log("You lost, it was " + upcommingcard);
    alert("You lost, it was " + upcommingcard);
    stop = 1;
  }
}
while (stop != 1);
```

Now, do compare the JS snippet above with your working Java code you've posted. If you compare again with your JS code, you should be able see what I meant by having different logic.